# Working with Dependency injection in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am trying to use Dependency injection in following way, however I am getting below error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   '' while attempting to activate ''.

What I am trying to achieve is, I have defined some common methods in generic interface and other methods where data driven logic will differ written down in repository specific interface Like ICustomerRepository.

And from controller these common and specific methods should be called. However as stated I am getting the above error when trying to execute API.

The reason why I kept generic repositories as those should not get added in StartUp.cs as and when added per repository.

So, how can execute generic and non generic methods through repository specific interface ?

Any help on this appreciated !

Below is my code

**IGenericRepository.cs**

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        TEntity GetById(int id);
        void Create(TEntity entity);
        Task Update(int id, TEntity entity);
        TEntity Delete(int id);
    }
```

**GenericRepository.cs**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TEntity Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public Task Update(int id, TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerable<TEntity> IGenericRepository<TEntity>.GetAll()
    {
        return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

**ICustomerRepository.cs**

```
public interface ICustomerRepository : IGenericRepository<Customer>
    {
        Task<Customer> GetCustomerDetails();
    }
```

**CustomerRepository.cs**

```
 public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
    {
        private readonly BaseDBContext _dbContext;

        public CustomerRepository(BaseDBContext dbContext)
            : base(dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public Task<Customer> GetCustomerDetails()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Customer.cs**

```
 public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
    }
```

**StartUp.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<BaseDBContext>();

            services.Configure<DBConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("DBConfiguration"));

            services.AddScoped<DbContext, BaseDBContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        }
```

**CustomerController.cs**

```
private readonly ICustomerRepository custRepository;

        public ValuesController(IOptions<DBConfiguration> dBConfiguration, ICustomerRepository _custRepository)
        {
            custRepository= _custRepository;
        }
```

Comment: You are injecting `ICustomerRepository`, which the container knows nothing about. Hence the error. Just because you registered the generic interface does not mean it will know about the derived interface and its implementation.

Comment: @Nkosi Agree but then how can achieve this ?

Comment: Someone already provided a valid answer

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah but I am not looking in that way

Comment: @Nkosi There is no any other way round/alternate solution ?

Comment: If you do not add `ICustomerRepository/CustomerRepository ` to contaner, how else do you expect the container to be able to resolve/inject it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196648/discussion-between-xamdev-and-nkosi).

Comment: The hoops people go through for completely unnecessary things. You can save yourself a ton of time, effort and energy by simply *not using repositories*. `DbContext` is your unit of work, and each `DbSet` is a repository. When you use an ORM like EF, you are simply opting to use a third-party DAL. Why in heaven people think they need to wrap their own DAL around that is beyond me. Normally, someone will chime in: to abstract the EF dependency. Really? Your repository depends on it directly, and you're even leaking it into the app `Startup`. Doesn't seem very "abstracted" to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your StartUp.cs

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
```

Comment: Nope, I don't want to do in that way... It will result in adding number of repositories in startup.cs file. I want to implement in generic way

Comment: @XamDev Then do a registration by convention. You can choose to register all concrete types as the interfaces they implement, or you can add a marker interface to only do that for certain types.

Comment: [This blog entry](https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/) shows how to use Scrutor to do that with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.